# Error while creating a trigger

Tags: oracle, triggers, oracle10g

The following trigger will update the values of other column in the table for every insert made for the particular column, but somehow I'm getting the following error.

> ORA-04084: cannot change NEW values for this trigger type

even the update statement did not seem to work in the trigger body;

```
create or replace trigger encode_trigger 
after insert on vulnerable_tags
for each row
declare 
  var1 varchar2(20);
  var2 varchar2(40);
begin
  var1 := :OLD.tag_name;
  var2 := Encode12(var1);
  :NEW.ascii_tags := var2;
end;
/
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to change the value in a column, you'd need to use a `BEFORE INSER OR UPDATET` trigger, not an `AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE` trigger.

```
create or replace trigger encode_trigger 
before insert on vulnerable_tags
for each row
declare 
var1 varchar2(20);
var2 varchar2(40);
begin
var1:= :OLD.tag_name;
var2:=Encode12(var1);
:NEW.ascii_tags:=var2;
end
```

do you need `after` for a specific reason?